# SE sites with low traffic should have moderators with low power

Tags: feature-request

In sites where traffic is low one moderator can pretty much decide the fate of all questions for a night.

Most users have question that they ask like once a week. if they happen to meet that moderator at that time the whole site come off as useless.

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll need to explain in more detail *what the problem is*. (Also, since you've used [[meta-tag:feature-request]], what feature are you requesting??)

Comment: Do you have a question? A proposal?

Comment: Is the closure of this [recommendation-request](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/903) the motivation for your question here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They is a tricky time in the life of many new sites after they have graduated from beta and have some solid momentum but still have too few closing- and deletion-empowered members to regularly and quickly take out the trash. During that time moderators and their powers are especially badly needed.

This is of course, also a time when those mods should be taking input from their community and be willing to *change their minds* if needed..

As the site grows there comes a time when the mods need to deliberately hang back so the growing community has to take the initiative.

But every site needs some human exception handlers.

Answer (score 12):

In the [Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), it's suggested that moderators guide the community with a firm, yet light hand, and wield the power bestowed on them with great respect and caution.

As a moderator, a comment can oftentimes carry much more weight than that of a regular user, and some moderators may use their influence to try and help improve a situation instead of resorting to the actual features of being a moderator. This is especially effective in existing communities where there exists a community of experienced users that can vote on certain actions.

In general, a moderator exists mostly for exceptional situations that must be dealt with immediately. These are the *exceptional* circumstances.

But on a newer or lower traffic site, there may not be enough participating members of that community to participate in the voting process; therefore, many times, the moderator must take it upon him or herself to make a decision. Sometimes it's correct, sometimes it's not.

In cases where you disagree with an action, politely and respectfully take the issue to meta. Make your case using facts, references, and evidence to prove your case. Cite the FAQ or Meta Stack Overflow posts to support your argument.  Most moderators I've encountered willing to listen to the opinions of others and reverse decisions if a good argument is presented. Just remember you're dealing with a real human being with real feelings and the stress of oftentimes standing alone, so you'll be more likely to gain respect and make your argument be heard if you also operate based on the guidelines in the Theory of Moderation. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

Just to get straight to the point, if you are complaining about this question

https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/903/best-online-sites-to-find-small-work-locally-or-online

being closed, you should read the [help center](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

I'll quote here some relevant parts

> **To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …**
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

In general questions like *"Best ... to do ..."* are considered primarily opinion-based and therefore not answerable.

The moderator closed the question and this is the reason, which you didn't understand. Let me put some emphasis on it.

> "This question does not appear to be about freelancing **within the scope defined in the help center**"

Your question is about freelancing, but it's not in format acceptable on StackExchange.

Comment: As the mod who closed that question, I would have to say this is the reason it was closed (just to re-affirm). There is a blog post that explains how to ask a better quality question, with much better results, based on the philosophy "teach a man to fish". I will add more details in the morning as a comment on that question.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question: No.

Moderators of any SE site should have the full power to do their job. Remember that they are *us*, just with more experience; this is a community, and you, me and them are all part of it.

If you are seeing posts "moderated" is a way you don't like, then you should be either posting the example here for discussion, or learning the (perhaps painful) lesson from it so that your posts can improve.

Perhaps it would help for you to read all of the help pages that are linked at the top and bottom of every SE page.

Answer (score 3):

I closed the Freelancing question as it is primarily opinion based, and therefore not a good fit for a Q&A site. It is a shopping recommendation, and does not fit within the scope of a good question, as shown in the Help Center. You can try checking the other links that levelnis posted in the comments, or try a Google search; even better would be to **edit** the question though, and ask for how to *find* a good site that has features x, y and z. Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, feed him forever.

As others have posted, moderators do make mistakes; as a new mod, I expect I will make mistakes. But we are also a community, of all users. We have ways of talking to the moderators, and I am thankful for them. We have Chat, Comments, Flagging systems, and the best of all, Meta. On the other main site of mine, I have spent lots of time talking with the Moderators in all four of those systems, whether I agree or not with an action. When the community decides on a change, it usually happens. Again, no one is perfect.

I apologize if that question on Freelancing is not the one you're talking about, but I figured since it was linked here, that I should step in and explain myself. I'd rather learn from my mistakes (if any have been made in this decision) rather then scare off new users. I'd rather have questions asked of me that keeps me honest, rather then scare off new users. The StackExchange network gives us this ability, and is one of the few sites where the mods work so closely with the community!

I hope this helps with what the original issue was, and I invite you to comment on here, ping me in the Freelancing chat, flag a post with a custom Mod message, or bring up the issue in the Meta (if it's about just Freelancing, then probably best in the Freelancing meta site).

Answer (score 2):

> SE sites with low traffic should have moderators with low power.
>   In sites where traffic is low one moderator can pretty much decide the fate of all questions for a night.

Let me start off by agreeing with you.

A rogue moderator *can* change the direction of a low-traffic site in a matter of minutes with a few arbitrary unanimous close votes. I've seen this happen twice.

*However...*
Both moderators didn't last. Each Community expressed their frustrations with said moderators and both were gone within a year.

In both cases, I'd have to say that the damage with done by the individuals doing the moderation. The damage was *not* caused by a disproportionate amount of power granted to the moderator position.

So I'm not sure which remedy you are proposing, but I'm inclined to agree with [@jmort253](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202921/13195).

> ...On a newer or lower traffic site, there may not be enough participating members of that community to participate in the voting process; therefore, many times, the moderator must take it upon him or herself to make a decision. Sometimes it's correct, sometimes it's not.

Comment: there is no way to weed out such individuals and to protect innocent members power of all there must be lowered so damage can be minimized. Till better community arises. It's better to let 3 wrong questions get away than let one good question be closed.